# Lambda calculus: "succ expressions" are all polynomial functions on Church numerals?

Tags: lambda-calculus

The specific definition of $\mathsf{succ}$ for Church numerals

$$ \mathsf{succ} = \lambda n f x. f (n f x) $$

seems to have an interesting property when applied to itself: (here, all expressions on $n$ mean the Church numeral that represents the value expressed by the value of $n$)

$$ \begin{align}
\mathsf{succ} \; \mathsf{succ} \; n f x &= (n^2+n) f x \\
\mathsf{succ} \; \mathsf{succ} \; \mathsf{succ} \; n f x &= (n^2+n+1) f x \\
\mathsf{succ} \; \mathsf{succ} \; \mathsf{succ} \; \mathsf{succ} \; n f x &= (n^3+n^2+n) f x \\
\mathsf{succ} \; \mathsf{succ} \; \mathsf{succ} \; \mathsf{succ} \; \mathsf{succ} \; n f x &= (n^3+n^2+n+1) f x
\end{align} $$

More generally these formulas hold:

$$ \begin{align}
\underbrace{\mathsf{succ} \; \cdots \; \mathsf{succ}}_{2k \text{ times}}
\; n f x &= (\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}{n^i}) f x \\
\underbrace{\mathsf{succ} \; \cdots \; \mathsf{succ}}_{2k+1 \text{ times}}
\; n f x &= (\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}{n^i}) f x
\end{align} $$

A proof attempt is [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55243859#55243859).

Now, imagine more general LC terms made of $\mathsf{succ}$s, such as $\mathsf{succ} (\mathsf{succ} \; \mathsf{succ})$, $\mathsf{succ} (\mathsf{succ} (\mathsf{succ} \; \mathsf{succ}) \mathsf{succ})$, etc. Are these polynomial functions on Church numerals as well? I once did some experiments, and more recently wrote a [Mathematica program](https://tio.run/##dVHBTsMwDL3nK3xkI2zaB8CNOxdO1lPkdouoRCLGWikF7dtLnG5TCuKQ2Infe85zgvRvhyB918o0vXx2sWcj8USPdBralm8bsMjjEDjm6MEJtN1u6NvQTEkOPOb15UAPTzRy4jGfAHtFFLJDKZf8fleKl/tSDzn6GrMO2k1h3l0VFKH9Fkrzm2o9v9T8xQgV42bAF8DduwQWSz57yBgBsCL1SqLl19gdhwODzjW3JmpoLEnmC7jBPwKWmr96yh2dpeR0nEU2LVyV0asNczYw8989pw@Je84/CEzTDw) that "evaluates" such expressions via term rewriting, but I'm yet to find a rigorous proof that this holds for *all* such terms, or a proven counterexample. I can't even imagine where to start.